# how to store date and time on parse

Tags: java, android, date, time, parse-platform

I'm trying to create an application where people store dates that will be used for reminders later on while using parse as a backend. The problem is whenever the date is stored on parse, the stored values are different from the ones I put. I'm in Kenya so I don't know if this is an issue with the timezone or how I'm storing the date. Here's a simple version of my code:

```
int month=2, date=27, mYear=2015, hours= 3, min =55;
Calendar myCalender =  Calendar.getInstance();
myCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
myCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
myCalender.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
myCalender.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
myCalender.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

//Then later on:
ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("TestDate");
obj.put("myDate", myCalender.getTime());
obj.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: What are the stored values you get? Do the stored values mention the time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parse API uses UTC](https://parse.com/questions/timezone-for-pfobjects), so your solution is probably to force Calendar to UTC timezone:

```
Calendar myCalender =  Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

I'd think the API would do the conversion, but seems like it doesn't

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That small change made my dates to store perfectly.

Comment: @PatriceAndala You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer then, so I can get my reputation boost :)

Comment: I would but I'm still new so I don't have the privilege

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between java.sql.Date and java.util.Date. Store date as setTimeInMillis(long millis) and getTimeInMillis().

Comment: I haven't used the date class even though it produced the same results. The date that ends up getting stored on parse seems always 4 hours into the future. Could this be an issue with parse or an issue with the code?